# Why unique_ptr::reset deletes the object AFTER replacement

Tags: c++

I think everything is in the question.
I wonder why the unique_ptr deletion is handled like this :

```cpp
auto ptr = m_ptr;
m_ptr = newPtr;
delete ptr;
```

and not

```cpp
delete m_ptr;
m_ptr = newPtr;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is answered by a note in the standard:

> [`[unique.ptr.single.modifiers/4]:`](http://eel.is/c++draft/unique.ptr.single.modifiers#4) *Effects:* Assigns `p` to the stored pointer, and then if and only if the old value of the stored pointer, `old_­p`, was not equal to `nullptr`, calls `get_­deleter()(old_­p)`. ***[Note:* The order of these operations is significant because the call to `get_­deleter()` may destroy `*this`. *— end note]***

In other words, it may not be `delete ptr` but some other more complex thing (inside the deleter), and if that complex thing nukes the `unique_ptr` itself, assigning to the stored pointer would have undefined behaviour.

I can't explain why the deleter would do that, though.

Also, note that `get_deleter()` (per the preceding paragraph) is not permitted to throw exceptions.